# How to get some values greater than the average in neo4j using cypher?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I want to assign a decision tree to my existing neo4j graph database. I have to create a decision tree that tells me that the price is cheap or expensive. In order to do so I have defined cheap as lower than the average price and expensive as greater. I tried the following code in cypher but it is not working.

I also want to make different other decisions but this is the easiest one. Also, another thing is if I can implement the decision tree on some python code and connect it to the existing neo4j database???

```
MAtch (p:Price),(ch:Cheap)

WITH avg(toFloat(p.monthly)) as average

Where ch.price <  average

MERGE (p)-[:IS_CHEAP]->(ch)
```

I expect a relation to be created between the node that has values (Price) and another node on the decision tree (Cheap) defined by taking lower values of price than the average.

Comment: Is your second question about how to connect to your graph through a python script and then execute that query?

Comment: @JohnS No i know how to connect it with bolt and everything but I wanted to know if there is a way to get the greater than average value in cypher and to assign it to another node as a decision node of a decision tree?

Comment: You can split the two tasks in two queries: 1. Find the average and create node 2. Find the nodes which have lower values than that node.

Comment: DO you have Cheap node already in the database?

Comment: @Raj Yes i have already a decision tree which has this cheap node already inside. But it is giving me errors while running the above query in order to get the average and create a relation of those products that have the price lower than average to the cheap node in the decision tree

Comment: @Raj What you suggest is to create a node that will store all the average price and then  use this node to define the products that have the price lower than the average and connect them to cheap node??]

Comment: You are comparing average and price of the Cheap node, do you have a price for Cheap node or did you mean Price node in the where condition?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your queries, what property has the price value.
I am assuming the monthly property has the price for Price nodes.

You can first find the average price, then use the same average value to find Price nodes with price less than that:

```
// Find Average Price
MATCH (p:Price)
WITH avg(toFloat(p.monthly)) as average
// Find Price nodes with price less than average
MATCH (p:Price), (ch:Cheap)
WHERE p.monthly < average

MERGE (p)-[:IS_CHEAP]->(ch)
```

Comment: The idea is like this: I have a node PRICE and monthly is the monthly price for a product. Now what I want to do is to implement decision trees to get either cheap or expensive products based on some input. I have created a decision tree that has a node cheap and a node expensive (if not cheap). Now I define the cheap as lower than the average monthly price and I want to get those products that have this cheap monthly price and link them to cheap node on decision tree. Thats all!!

Comment: No actually is not working because i want to connect a decision graph to an existing graph I have and to be able to find products that have a price lower than the average price

Comment: I added a picture to be more clear, you can find it above